# Basic US phone regex not picking up area code

Tags: regex

I made this regex `(\([0-9]\)\s)?([0-9]{3})([\s-])([0-9]{4})` to find 4 basic phone formats.

555-1234

555 1234

(414) 555-1234

(414) 555 1234

It's not finding the phone numbers with the area code in parenthesis

Comment: `\([0-9]\)` There is no quantifier. It will only match a single digit in the parenthesis.

Comment: Ahhhhh that would be it! Thank you, I can only stare at regex for so long before the symbols turn into hieroglyphics.

Comment: Personally I'd just give up trying to validate the *exact* format of a phone number (unless I was writing a phone exchange or something). Maybe validate that the user has entered at least N digits and no letters and be done with it. I bet lots of people will write phone numbers in all sorts of bizarre ways.

Comment: I agree with Matti. You're going to hopelessly enrage your users if they don't match one of your very strict inputs.

Comment: I agree 100%, however I'm in my senior year and just trying to get this assignment done for a piece of paper called a diploma. :/

Comment: @Programatic sorry it would be a huge violation of my personal philosophies to exert effort helping you learn something that I believed to be wrong. It's a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are senselessly rigid. These are all valid US phone numbers

```
1234567
123 4567
123-4567
123 - 4567
123 456 7890
123.456.7890
(123) 4567890
+1 (123) 456-7890
+1 123-456-7890
```

And countless other permutations.

Don't be a pain in your user's neck. Write regexps that are friendly

```
/^(?:\+1\s*)?(?:(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})\s*[.-]?\s*)?\d{3}\s*[.-]?\s*\d{4}$/
```

[image: regexp visualization]

This allows for:

- optional leading region code `+1` (North America)
- optional spaces, `.`, `-`, or combination of these to be used as a separator
- optional area code
- optional area code wrapped in `()`

---

If you want to accept a wide variety of user inputs but store them in a uniform format in your system, that's easy too. Use *capture groups* in the regexp to extract the numbers that are relevant.

```
/^(?:\+1\s*)?(?:(?:\((\d{3})\)|(\d{3}))\s*[.-]?\s*)?(\d{3})\s*[.-]?\s*(\d{4})$/
```

To create capture groups, you can use `()`. Notice the use of capture groups around `\d{3}` and `\d{4}`.

Now in our code, we can use capture groups. This example code uses JavaScript

```
const truthy = x => !!x;

const formatPhoneNumber = n => {
  // regexp that we made above
  let re = /^(?:\+1\s*)?(?:(?:\((\d{3})\)|(\d{3}))\s*[.-]?\s*)?(\d{3})\s*[.-]?\s*(\d{4})$/;
  // destructure the capture groups
  let [match, area1, area2, part1, part2] = re.exec(n);
  // reassemble the parts as desired
  return [area1 || area2, part1, part2].filter(truthy).join('-')
}
```

Now let's define our sample data and see how each number gets formatted

```
let xs = [
  '1234567',
  '123 4567',
  '123-4567',
  '123 - 4567',
  '123 456 7890',
  '123.456.7890',
  '(123) 4567890',
  '+1 (123) 456-7890',
  '+1 123-456-7890',
];

xs.map(formatPhoneNumber);
```

Notice each phone number *input* was vastly different, but the *output* is **100% uniform**.

```
[
    "123-4567",
    "123-4567",
    "123-4567",
    "123-4567",
    "123-456-7890",
    "123-456-7890",
    "123-456-7890",
    "123-456-7890",
    "123-456-7890"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
/(\([\s\d]+\)\s*)?\d+[\s\-]*\d+/g
```